# Is it safe to add foreign key constraint on two columns, while one is not unique (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a `users` table and other tables such as `services`, `orders`, etc... that are I would like to turn into child tables of the `users` table.

So far it's simple, I just add Foreign Key Constraint between `users(id)` and `orders(user_id)`. But what if I'd like to add a Boolean `users(disabled)` field, that would cascade the update to the `orders(disabled)` and `services(disabled)` fields in the rows that reference the respective row in `users` via `(user_id)` key?

Would it work if I create a reference in the child table to the parent table using 2 keys, one primary and one non unique?

Comment: I read that InnoDB in MySQL allows it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have probably answered your question yourself if you'd have tried it. Basically, you can't create a **foreign key** relation on columns that are not part of a primary key on the *foreign* table (as the name implies).

So, unless the `disabled` column is part of the primary key on the `users` table, then, no, you won't be able to create a foreign key relation in another table that would include the `disabled` column.

All is not lost though. You could use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to *trigger* the disabling of orders and services when a user becomes disabled.